# Angular 5 can't call method 'post' in WebApi

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api

I want to call a function in Web api from angular 5

This is my function in api.service.ts:

```js
//it works
public getAllTodos() {
    return this.http
      .get(API_URL + '/todos/')
      .map(response => {
        const todos = response.json();
        return todos.map((todo) => new Todo(todo));
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  
  //it doesn't work
  public createTodo(todo: Todo) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });        
    //let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let payload = JSON.stringify(todo);
    return this.http
      //.post(API_URL + '/todos/', JSON.stringify(todo), options)
      .post(API_URL + '/todos/', payload, {headers: headers})
      .map(response => {
        return new Todo(response.json());
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This is my function in Web Api:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("todos")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllTodos()
    {
        try
        {                
            List<Todo> todos = manager.GetAll().ToList();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, todos);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("todos")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateTodo([FromBody] Todo todo)
    {
        try
        {
            Todo td = new Todo() { title = todo.title, complete = todo.complete };
            int id = manager.CreateTodo(td);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I set a breakpoint in Web API but it doesn't receive any call from angular client. However, it works for 'get' method.

Please tell my why function 'post' doesn't work and solution to solve it.

I attach the image below.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: did you checked the developer's tool & network tab?

Comment: @brk there is no request to 'post' function in Network tab even though I set the breakpoint in Chrome and it runs.

Comment: how are you calling  `createTodo` function?

Comment: same as 'get' method, in the code above

Comment: 1) What does your Network tab show in devtools? 2) Did you enable CORS on WebApi side?

Comment: @deezg yes, I enable CORS. The method 'get' is OK but 'post' errors. I think headers seem to be the problem.

Comment: yes but what are the errors? can you show your Console&Network tab?

Comment: The error is the Web api doesn't receive the request from angular client. I set breakpoint and don't see any request for 'CreateTodo' function but 'GetAllTodos' function works.

Comment: Are you using `InMemoryDataService` in your project?

Comment: No, where to put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you are facing has to do with the mismatch of the sent object and the expected object on `Web API`.

Have you tried passing the `todo` object in the body instead of stringifying it?

Try this

```
post(API_URL + '/todos/', todo, {headers: headers})
```

The other reason for the request not being made at all is if you are not subscribing to it. Don’t forget that `Observables` are lazy.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. The network tab doesn't show any 'post' request.

Comment: No error is displayed.
No request from client, I don't understand why :(

Comment: Wait a minute are doing subscribe on the createTodo method? Unless you do a subscribe it won’t trigger the request

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? And please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a link to the documentation. But basically what you need to do is wherever your createTodo method is being called, you need to do createTodo.subscribe(). Unless you do this the request will not be fired because http returns an observable. It’s a cold observable, meaning it won’t do anything until you have someone subscribing to it.

Comment: Oh damn it, I add .subscribe in app.component.ts and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Always glad to help. Please don’t forget to set the answered check to help others in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you are calling the createTodo method ensure that you are subscribing. Refer below for code snippet:

```
this._service.createTodo(todoobject).subscribe(success=>{},error=>{});
```